# Where can I find a complete list of all the logs in the system?

Tags: linux, logging, forensics

I'd like to learn more about forensic analysis, and I'm trying to do the challenges from [Project Honeynet](http://www.honeynet.org/). I need to check the logfiles and find the IP's that connected remotely to the computer. I have a `dd` made image of the harddrive. I think the only service that was running was `apache`. Besides Apache's logs, what other log files should I check? Where are they located?

Answer (score 2):

You could look at /var/log/wtmp using the command who.  This will show you who has logged on to the system.  I think it shows Ip's but not completely sure.  This of course would only apply to *nix machines.

Edit:  After re-reading the post I suspect you were looking more for a log of who made connections to your webserver?  This won't show you anything like that, just who accessed a shell I think.

Comment: Yes. I'm searching for connections made to the system.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what system you're running, but I'll guess a recent Linux: there's a whole plethora of logs awaiting your inspection under /var/log.  Other systems may have put them elsewhere.  Nearly all of these could have useful connect information.